# Content of file not printing

Tags: python-3.x, file, read-write

I am a beginner, learning programming using python 3.7. I am running a basic program to read content of a file after writing on it. But the print function won't print out the content of the file on the terminal. Can you please correct what mistake I am making here:

```
spam = input("What file would you like to open. Type the name below\n>>>")
# for the file name I type example.txt
work = open(spam, "r+")
work.write(input("Now write something on the file here\n>>"))
x = work.read()
print(x)


work.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

After the `write()` completes, the file's object index needs to be moved to the beginning of the file

add `work.seek(0)` before the `read()` operation

```
spam = input("What file would you like to open. Type the name below\n>>>")
# for the file name I type example.txt
work = open(spam, "r+")
work.write(input("Now write something on the file here\n>>"))
work.seek(0)
x = work.read()
print(x)


work.close()
```

Comment: Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek

Answer (score -1):

You can't actually read your spam variable since it is not a file.
Instead:

```
work = open("NewFile.txt", "w")
work.write(spam)
work.close()
```